# binary operator error in `if` function

Tags: r

I wrote the following function:

```
x    <- 1:4
y    <- c(1,2,7,4)
mydf <- data.frame(a=x,b=x,c=x,d=x,y=y)

practice  <-  function(x) if( x[1] == x[5]) {

             foo <- (x[2])
             return(foo)

              } else {

              bar     <- x[3] + x[4]                
              foobar <- x[2] - bar

               return(foobar)
              }       

newmydf <- apply( mydf, 1, practice)
```

this works fine on the `data.frame` provided. However I have another `data.frame` and I keep getting

```
Error in x[3] + x[4] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

despite the following `str()`

```
'data.frame':   133 obs. of  19 variables:
 $  : chr   ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : int   ...
 $ : int  ...
 $ : num  ...
 $ : int  
 $ : int
```

What possible little slip ups can I be making? I have started with a new session and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(mydf))` (or whatever the name of your data frame that's not working is?)

Comment: If you send the data frame you've shown through apply, you will convert each row to a character vector because of the first column.  Instead, run it with `apply(mydf[, 2:length(mydf)], 1, practice)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values in the first column of second data frame are of type "character". As a result, the command `apply` turns the whole data frame into a character matrix. The operator `+` is not defined for character values.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Transform the first column to type numeric (if possible):

   ```
   mydf[ , 1] <- as.numeric(mydf[ , 1])
   ```
2. Do not use the first column of the data frame:

   ```
   apply(mydf[ , -1], 1, practice)
   ```

Comment: Even better would probably be to turn the first column into rownames, usually the right choice for a data frame where every column except one is numeric. That would let you keep the column.

Comment: wow I have used `apply` so many times and I never new that it. Thats a kicker. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use `by`:

```
# Put in a character to mydf to test
mydf$foo<-'a'
# Run by
by(mydf,seq(nrow(mydf)),practice)
```